# Is linkedList.listIterator(linkedList.size()) optimized?

Tags: java, linked-list, reverse, listiterator

I'm trying to create a reverse `ListIterator` for a `LinkedList`, and was going to just implement it as a wrapper to `linkedList.listIterator(linkedList.size())` that swaps the `next` and `previous` operations, but then realized that if `LinkedList#listIterator(int)` is implemented to just traverse forwards to the position specified, using it to start at the end would be terribly unoptimized, having to traverse the list twice rather than once, when the list supports going directly to the end. Is `linkedList.listIterator(linkedList.size())` optimized to not traverse the entire list?

Comment: That is pretty implementation specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ListIterator uses indexes to identify which element to start at. [In the Oracle docs for LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), it says:

> All of the operations perform as could be expected for a doubly-linked
>   list. Operations that index into the list will traverse the list from
>   the beginning or the end, whichever is closer to the specified index.

Thus when you do `linkedList.listIterator(linkedList.size())`, it will traverse the list backwards exactly 0 steps to grab the correct index. So, you could say that it's as optimized as it possibly can be. Go ahead and wrap that iterator.

Answer (score 1):

It is optimized, it's here

```
private class ListItr implements ListIterator<E> {
```

...

```
ListItr(int index) {
    // assert isPositionIndex(index);
    next = (index == size) ? null : node(index);
    nextIndex = index;
}
```

...

```
Node<E> node(int index) {
    // assert isElementIndex(index);

    if (index < (size >> 1)) {  <-- if index less than half size go forward
        Node<E> x = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            x = x.next;
        return x;
    } else {                     <-- otherwise backwards
        Node<E> x = last;
        for (int i = size - 1; i > index; i--)
            x = x.prev;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Source for the implementation?

Comment: It is in my JDK - src.zip

Comment: @Quirliom Grepcode is also a good resource if you can't pull apart src.zip readily: [ListItr in LinkedList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.ListItr).